# Bower package won't update?

Tags: git, bower, package

I've forked a **bower** package, edited and registered it.

I made some changes and pushed those into the master branch at github.

The package is included within another project and if I want to update the package now, I won't get the updated files?

Furthermore I've tried to uninstall and install the package again but it seems to load only from the original commit. Is there a way to fix this?

[Link to Repository](https://github.com/Poolshark/AdminLTE)

Bower package: `bower install admin-lte-sass`

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the link, or code snippet to the project where you are consuming the `admin-lte-sass`. Just `bower install admin-lte-sass`, nothing more? T̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶. Oh, you've changed the name of the package..

Comment: I've forked the package from [here](https://github.com/aguegu/AdminLTE). As in my opinion some paths were broken and some plugins where missing, I've changed that and pushed it to the main branch. `bower install admin-lte-sass` should work (it does for me). Could it be the tagging? Does bower not  fetch from the latest commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why, but I guess it has something to do with the versioning and tagging of the project. I think bower will only fetch the updated files if it is tagged as a new version?

Anyway, if I add the branch name it will fetch from the latest commit and everything is fine.

```
bower install admin-lte-sass#master
```

will do the job and fetch from my latest commit on the master branch. I guess that is not the right way to do it and I'd appreciate it if someone has any comments about how to work with this correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

please go for bower global install.
If possible delete the bower component from %AppData% folder
and then go for

```
bower -g install admin-lte-sass
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this should help? Why would I want to install the package globally? As I'm pretty new with all this I guess I could try adding the `--save-dev` flag but I'm not sure if that is the right way to do it.

Comment: So my guess is that you have not gone for global installation.Then you wont face any problem.Sometime if you are installing a npm package or bower component etc globally its creates issue with content in the %AppData% folder if you are using windows.Use bower cache clean and go for bower install admin-lte-sass.

Comment: I've tried cleaning the cache already - did not make any difference. Also global installation did not work for me. The only thing which worked was referring specifically to the master branch (see my answer), but I'm not 100% happy with this solution as I see it as a dirty hack...

Comment: yeah,updating devDependencies is perfect!